# C++ auto , don't understand how assign operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have this code .

```
CGraphicTextInstance*& prGuildNameInstance = pTextTail->pGuildNameTextInstance;
```

And i want to apply some c++11 features like `auto` transform.

After auto should look like this:

```
auto prGuildNameInstance = pTextTail->pGuildNameTextInstance;
```

After add auto the auto assign just `CGraphicTextInstance` without operators `*&` I saw this with intelisense.

My question is why ?  Should i add manually missing operators ? like this ?

```
auto &prGuildNameInstance = pTextTail->pGuildNameTextInstance;
```

My question can this damage my codes ?
Can this be a problem ?
Is ok to let auto assign what he want ?

Comment: `auto` is supposed to use the most appropriate variable type for the usage that you do to it. So if this is your only piece of code, `auto` won't think very much, as you don't do anything of the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` (mostly) uses the same rules as template deduction to deduce the type. As such, it will strip references, so you need to be explicit about taking a reference:

```
auto prGuildNameInstance = pTextTail->pGuildNameTextInstance;
//prGuildNameInstance is of type CGraphicTextInstance*

auto& prGuildNameInstance = pTextTail->pGuildNameTextInstance;
//prGuildNameInstance is of type CGraphicTextInstance*&
```

The choice is essentially the same as for any variable: if you want a reference, ask for a reference; if you want a value, ask for a value.

Comment: Thanks for answed. But is possible to make auto to assing automatically  both  *& ?

Comment: @Ramy not really, that would break the language.